# Abbreviating LastName, Firstname in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to format the player name to LAST, F. and not the full name.
So basically I want to cut the string 2 spaces after every comma and add a .(period)

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<fbgame>
 <team>
   <player name="LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME"></player>
</team>
 </fbgame>
```

this is the xslt code block

```
<name>
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</name>
```

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or above?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using xslt 2.0,

```
<name>
  <xsl:variable name="fullname" select="tokenize(@name, ',')" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($fullname[1], ',',substring($fullname[2],1,2),'.')"/>
</name>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the comma after the last name in your output.

Comment: Yeah. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="player">
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@name, ', ')" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(@name, ', '), 1, 1)" />
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    </name>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="player">
    <name>
        <xsl:variable name="last" select="substring-before(@name, ', ')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(@name, 1, string-length($last) + 3)" />
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    </name>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another XSLT 2.0 option:

```
<xsl:template match="player">
  <name>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(@name,'([^,]+, .).*','$1.')"/>
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```